# tensorflow keras import issues when loading retinanet model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
%matplotlib inline
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
# external modules


from tensorflow import keras
from keras_retinanet import models
from keras_retinanet.utils.image import read_image_bgr, preprocess_image, resize_image
from keras_retinanet.utils.visualization import draw_box, draw_caption
from keras_retinanet.utils.colors import label_color
from keras_retinanet.utils.gpu import setup_gpu
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import time
import csv
import math
import utm
import shapefile
import scipy
from scipy.spatial import distance
from urllib.request import urlopen

# internal modules
from utils import *




# set file path
root = os.getcwd()
rcnn_model_root = os.path.join(root, "trained_models")
input_gsv_root = os.path.join(root, "input_gsv")
output_gsv_root = os.path.join(root, "output_gsv")
output_shp_root = os.path.join(root, "output_shp")



rcnn_model_name = "resnet101_csv_25_inference.h5"
rcnn_model_path = os.path.join(rcnn_model_root,rcnn_model_name)
model = models.load_model(rcnn_model_path)
```

Every time I try to run this code I get issues with keras/tensorflow imports.

AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'

I was told to do from keras import tensorflow or something like that, but then I get other issues like not recognizing Freeze. This was run by someone else with a specific configuration, so downgrading packages has not worked.

Comment: Which version of TF do you use?

Answer (score 0):

`keras_retinanet` repository is deprecated to access from newer versions of **Tensorflow**.

However you can access this repository in `tensorflow 2.3.0` and `keras 2.4` by using below code.

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.3.0
!pip install keras==2.4
!pip install keras_retinanet
```

Please find this [link](https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet/blob/main/README.md) to get more details on `keras_retinanet` repository.